# two tables overlapping each other html

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to add vertical lines to my table that aligns with the headers and I'm using 'border-collapse: separate' as well as colspan that varies from 1 to any number. Here is an image to imagine it
[image]

Keeping in mind Cell1 has colspan of 3 and cell 2 has colspan of 2

but I would like to keep the separate border collapse for the view. My approach was to put two tables above each other one for the data with opacity:70% for example to show the table below it and the table below it should have the vertical lines with each header. However, I'm unable in anyway to put two tables in the same position.

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
            <table
            BORDER
        >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th >
                        H1
                    </th>
                    <th
                    >
                        H2
                    </th>
                    <th
                    >
                        H3
                    </th>
                    <th
                    >
                        H4
                    </th>
                    <th
                    >
                        H5
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <td colspan="3">
                Cell1
              </td>
              <td colspan="2">
                Cell2
              </td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle of the table

http://jsfiddle.net/vrL9s7ft/6/

Comment: question is a little bit confusing to me. Can you please clarify the expected result? Also, can you add a working code snippet of your existing html/css.

Comment: I added the table html code above. what I want is to show a fainted line vertically across the table that aligns with the end of each header. For example cell 1 has a colspan of 3 thus it should have 3 fainted lines across the whole cell that aligns with the headers ending H1, H2 and H3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have attached a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/whjnt5o2/1/

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

table{
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table.background-table{
  position: absolute;
}

table.background-table th, table.background-table td {
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table class="background-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>H1</th>
      <th>H2</th>
      <th>H3</th>
      <th>H4</th>
      <th>H5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td colspan="3">
      Cell1
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      Cell2
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```